# Is this the correct way of finding the inverse of a cycle?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

If I have a cycle $$g=(132)$$then the inverse cycle is found by writing it in a backwards order, in other words $$g^{-1}=(231)$$

Say now we have $g=(135)(24)$ and I want to find what $g^{-1}$ is.

As the two cycles are disjoint from each other, I am thinking that the inverse will simply be $$g^{-1}=(531)(42)$$

Is this correct? Also, as they are disjoint, I am thinking that the product commutes, so would this also be valid?

$$g^{-1}=(42)(531)$$

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It's correct, but sort of backwards. If we didn't know that the two cycles commuted the inverse would be $(42)(531)$; it's only because they do commute that the inverse is also $(531)(42)$.

Comment: I understand. We do the $(531)$ first to cancel the most recently done $(135)$. Could you make that an answer so I can tick it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every group $G$, we have the property, that for $x,y \in G$ it holds that 
$$ (xy)^{-1} = y^{-1}x^{-1} $$
(note the order!) to see this, note that 
\begin{align*}
  (xy)^{-1} &= (xy)^{-1}xx^{-1}\\
            &= (xy)^{-1}x(yy^{-1})x^{-1}\\
            &= (xy)^{-1}(xy)y^{-1}x^{-1}\\
            &= y^{-1}x^{-1} 
\end{align*}
Now apply this to $S_5$ (or what permutation group you are in). If $x$ and $y$ commute, we have $(xy)^{-1} = x^{-1}y^{-1}$ (this is an if and only if, so it is wrong for non-commuting elements!).